# Decreasing Loop Interval by 1 in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have 15 elements. I want to group them such a way that:

```
group1 = 1 - 5
group2 = 6 - 9
group3 = 10 - 12
group4 = 13 - 14
group5 = 15
```

This way I'll get elements in each group as below:

```
group1 = 5
group2 = 4
group3 = 3
group4 = 2
group5 = 1
```

As you can see loop interval is decreasing.

I took 15 just for an example. In actual programme it's user driven parameter which can be anything (hopefully few thousand).

Now what I'm looking for is:
Whatever is in group1 should have variable "loop" value 0, group2 should have 1, group3 should have 2 and so on... "loop" is an int variable which  is being used to calculate some other stuff.

### Let's put in other words too

I have an int variable called "loop". I want to assign value to it such a way that:
First n frames loop value 0 next (n -1) frames loop value 1 then next (n - 2) frames loop value 2 all the way to loop value (n - 1)

Let's say I have 15 frames on my timeline.

So n will be 5 ====>>>>> (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15; as interval is decreasing by 1)

then

first 5 frames(1 - 5) loop is 0 then next 4 frames(6 - 9) loop is 1 then next 3 frames(10 - 12) loop is 2 then next 2 frames(13 - 14) loop is 3 and for last frame(15) loop is 4.

```
frames       "loop" value
1 - 5    =>     0
6 - 9    =>     1
10 - 12  =>     2
13 - 14  =>     3
15       =>     4
```

I've tried with modulo(%). But the issue is on frame 12 loop is 2 so (12 % (5 - 2)) remainder is 0 so it increments loop value.
The following lines are sample code which is running inside a solver. @loop is by default 0 and @Frame is current processing frame number.

```
int loopint = 5 - @loop;

if (@Frame % loopint == 0)
    @loop += 1;
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Choose one.  Or maybe choose the language your code is actually written in, which does not appear to be either one.

Comment: It's written in VEX (http://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini15.5/vex/) which is similar to C. I'm looking for the algorithm. Either of C or C++ is fine.

Comment: You can ignore "@" sign before variable name.
Frame is current processing frame, you can think it as current index.

int loop = 0;
int loopint = 5 - loop;

if (Frame % loopint == 0)
    loop += 1;

Comment: I can't get what you mean. All of that seems a big mess in naming to me (except possibly the case those names come from your real-life problem, and they have nothing to do with ususal programming context). Generally speaking, I feel it's kind of XY problem (see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at Meta SE). Could you describe the real problem you're solving, not the minor sub-part of _a loop_ decrementing (?) the incrementation (?!) of a **variable** called _loop_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, then

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);

  for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    printf("%d: %f\n", i, ceil((sqrt(8 * (n - i + 1) + 1) - 1) / 2));
  }
}
```

is an implementation in C.

The math behind this is as follows: The 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 you have there is a Gauß sum, which has a closed form S = n * (n + 1) / 2 for n terms. Solving this for n, we get

```
n = (sqrt(8 * S + 1) - 1) / 2
```

Rounding this upward would give us the solution if you wanted the short stretches at the beginning, that is to say 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...

Since you want the stretches to become progressively shorter, we have to invert the order, so S becomes (n - S + 1). Therefore the formula up there.

EDIT: Note that unless the number of elements in your data set fits the n * (n+1) / 2 pattern precisely, you will have shorter stretches either at the beginning or in the end. This implementation places the irregular stretch at the beginning. If you want them at the end,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);

  int n2    = (int) ceil((sqrt(8 * n + 1) - 1) / 2);
  int upper = n2 * (n2 + 1) / 2;

  for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    printf("%d: %f\n", i, n2 - ceil((sqrt(8 * (upper - i + 1) + 1) - 1) / 2));
  }
}
```

does it. This calculates the next such number beyond your element count, then calculates the numbers you would have if you had that many elements.